# Batch Video Transcoding for the web OS X (GUI, not command line)

Tags: macos, video, encoding

Is there a way to batch transcode video files to mp4 and webm for HTML5 videos in OS X?

Our video department needs to hand over a lot of videos in multiple formats consistently. Workflow current consists of utilizing Adobe Media Encoder for the MP4s and Miro Video Converter for the WebM files.

The video guys are all very familiar with Adobe Media Encoder, so the ultimate solution would be to have everything run through there, but Adobe doesn't look like any time in the near future they're going to support WebM -- still pushing Flash player.

Miro Video Converter works great, but is lacking a way to queue/batch files.

I've Googled but have yet to come up with a good GUI-based solution the video team can use for batching the multiple formats need to ensure videos work on the web everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question, we ended up getting licenses for iSkySoft and for testing purposes, us developers use the newest version of Miro Video Converter which now has a batching option.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on [Sorenson Squeeze](http://www.sorensonmedia.com/video-encoding/).

It is a professionnal video encoding software supporting a lot of formats including WebM, mp4(h264).

It has an intuitive GUI like Adobe Media Encoder.